# How can duplicate a class in google classroom with google class api

Tags: google-classroom

I want to copy many classroom from the other one with API. In google classroom API course not have API copy but in the web https://classroom.google.com have copy class. I want to write API using google class API and driver API to copy classroom to many other classroom and copy files in folder driver too

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.